mysql data recovery from Time Machine
Because of some unfortunate events I had to remove mysql from my Mac Ventura completely. There was only one database I was using. Let's call it my_db.
Time Machine has backed up this database with all the other stuff, so I have it as a directory of files, called my_db.
After reinstalling mysql and placing the my_db where it belongs in the new installation, i.e. under /usr/local/var/mysql, mysql refuses to use it.
Any way I can fix this?
I would like mysql recognize the old my_db database.
PS. Before I get the advice to back stuff up regularly: I do. I have a db dump that is a few days older.

You should restore from your db dump. A backup of the MySQL directory from Time Machine is probably unusable for restoring, because it consists of multiple files, and they were not saved at the same moment.

Any way to figure out what the old version was from the backed up database?
